# Golang Gin "c.Param undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method Param)"

Tags: go, go-gin

I tried to use the Gin which is framework for Golang.
https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin

And the I copied sample codes from official github.
It's like this.

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/user/:name", func(c *gin.Context) {
        name := c.Param("name")
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello %s", name)
        })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

But I got the error.

```
# go run main.go
# command-line-arguments ./main.go:12: c.Param undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method Param)
```

Does anyone know how can I fix the problem ?

・CentOS7

・go version go1.6.3 linux/amd64

#### Edit:

I actually use the glide but I updated gin as global.
And also update Go to 1.7 but getting still the same error:

```
# go get -u -v github.com/gin-gonic/gin
github.com/gin-gonic/gin (download)
github.com/golang/protobuf (download)
Fetching https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup gopkg.in on 192.168.11.1:53: dial udp 192.168.11.1:53: i/o timeout
gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8 (download)
Fetching https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup gopkg.in on 192.168.11.1:53: dial udp 192.168.11.1:53: i/o timeout
gopkg.in/yaml.v2 (download)
github.com/manucorporat/sse (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/net/context?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/net/context?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/net/context": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/net", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/net"} at https://golang.org/x/net/context?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/net/context": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/net?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/net?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/net (download)

# go version
go version go1.7 linux/amd64

# go run test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:12: c.Param undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method Param)
```

Comment: your `go get -u -v github.com/gin-gonic/gin`  fetch failed:  Are you having proxy or internet connection problem ? try it again

Comment: oh,  I tried it again and there are no errors. but still it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
The OP had "vendor dir created by the Glide" with old version of package.
and problem solved by removing that folder (updating vendor package).

[Note](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies): `go get` never checks out or updates code stored in vendor directories.

---

`c.Param(key)` is a shortcut for `c.Params.ByName(key)`, see `c.Param(key)` Docs:

> ```
> // Param returns the value of the URL param.
> // It is a shortcut for c.Params.ByName(key)
> //        router.GET("/user/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
> //            // a GET request to /user/john
> //            id := c.Param("id") // id == "john"
> //        })
> func (c *Context) Param(key string) string {
>   return c.Params.ByName(key)
> }
> ```

---

You need to update  `github.com/gin-gonic/gin` package, try:

```
go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

And make sure there aren't any `vendor` and  try remove all files and vendor dir except `main.go` then `go build` (or update your vendor package).

---

Your code works fine in `go1.7`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/user/:name", func(c *gin.Context) {
        name := c.Param("name")
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello %s", name)
    })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Open in browser `http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/World`
output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: @k16  I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. I added the message to the original form. As I wrote it doesn't work. I think my docker environment something wrong, but also I don't think it depends on the server environment. it's weird. @Amd

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, but I had to import the http package:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
import "net/http"

func main() {
router := gin.Default()

router.GET("/user/:name", func(c *gin.Context) {
    name := c.Param("name")
    c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello %s", name)
    })

router.Run(":8080")
}
```

`go version` returns `go version go1.5.3 linux/amd64` for me.

It seems your error was on line 19 of your gin.go as per './main.go:19: c.Param undefined' what are the other lines in the script?

The provided script is only 14 lines long.

Comment: Thanks. I put correct source code and error again. But still getting the same error. hmmm, It looks depends on the Go version???

Comment: Yeah, I'd try to downgrade. I didn't see any information regarding the specific version of golang gin is confirmed for.

Answer (score 0):

I got the success.

The reason why is my directory depth.
I put the main.go at "/go/myproject/src/server/main.go" and set "export GOPATH=/go/myproject".

In this case, I got the error.
But after I changed the path of main.go at "/go/myproject/src/main.go", it works.

I was wondering that I didn't think that my directory structure is wrong.
I can put the main.go any depth, can't I ?

Added2

```
# pwd
/go/myproject/src/server
# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 ftp 633  8月 17 02:52 glide.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 ftp  78  8月 17 02:51 glide.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 ftp 254  8月 17 02:51 main.go
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 ftp 136  8月 17 02:52 vendor
# go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:12: c.Param undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method Param)
# cat main.go
package main

import (
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        router := gin.Default()

        router.GET("/user/:name", func(c *gin.Context) {
            name := c.Param("name")
            c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello %s", name)
        })

        router.Run(":8080")
}
```

But when I don't call the param function, like this , Gin looks working.

```
# cat main.go
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
        r := gin.Default()
        r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
        })
        r.Run(":8080")
}
# go run main.go
[GIN-debug] GET   /ping                     --> main.main.func1 (3 handlers)
[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :8080
[GIN] 2016/08/17 - 03:01:17 | 200 |     79.238µs | [::1]:41546 |   GET     /ping
```

The main.go is set at same place.

Comment: the path `/go/myproject/src/server/main.go` is OK, what is the  error ?

Comment: thank you. hmmm, the error means " c.Param undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method Param)".

Comment: is `main.go` the only file inside `/go/myproject/src/s‌​erver/` or there is another `*.go` file inside `/go/myproject/src/s‌​erver/`?

Comment: Yes, I put the additional information to this form which is below "added2". Actually, I have only main.go.

Comment: What's inside `vendor`, try remove all files and `vendor` dir   except `main.go`  then `go build`, is this OK? if so problem is vendor.

Comment: Awesome, it works. you are right. Thank you. vendor dir is created by the Glide. I wanted to manage packages in my project, so I tried to use the Glide. I guess probably the Gin can not read it selves packages downloaded by the Glide??? hmmm, I have another trouble. lol. I will try to use other package manager. anyway thank you for your greate help @Amd .

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. Glide now tries to use Semantic Versioning 2.0.0, which glide hasn't update in a while, setting the version manually to latest develop fixes the issue:

```
- package: github.com/gin-gonic/gin
  version: f931d1ea80ae95a6fc739213cdd9399bd2967fb6
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.
I'm not sure the root cause but I fixed it by changing the code from

```
c.Param("name")
```

to

```
c.Params.ByName("name")
```

If you look at the source for the `Param()` method, this is what it called under the covers.

Comment: No this is not an answer and this is another problem, see the all comments under all posts. `c.Param(key)` is a shortcut for `c.Params.ByName(key)`, see `Param(key)` docs. And update your package: `github.com/gin-gonic/gin`

Comment: agree the root cause was the use of an older version of the gin-gonic code.  Updated to the latest and the problem went away.