# How to get file posted from JSON in go gin?

Tags: json, go, go-gin

I want to save image file posted by JSON.

Here is the struct of the post:

```
type Article struct {
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Body string `json:"body"`
    File    []byte `json:"file"`
}
```

And the handler is :

```
   func PostHandler(c *gin.Context) {
        var err error
        var json Article
        err = c.BindJSON(&json)
        if err != nil {
            log.Panic(err)
        }

    //handle photo upload
        var filename string
        file, header, err := json.File  //assignment count mismatch: 3 = 1

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            filename = ""

        } else {
            data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }

            filename = path.Join("media", +shared.RandString(5)+path.Ext(header.Filename))

            err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, data, 0777)
            if err != nil {
                io.WriteString(w, err.Error())
                return
            }

        }
...
```

But I get

> assignment count mismatch: 3 = 1

I copied the file handling part from a working multipart form handler which worked fine but apparently,

```
file, header, err := r.FormFile("uploadfile")
```

can not be translated into JSON handling.

I have looked at gin docs but could not find examples involving json file handling. 
So how can I fix this?

Comment: You can use JSON to upload files if you base64 encode the file into a string, then base64 decode the string into a buffer (byte array) on the server. However, I recommend that you use the "multipart/form-data" approach instead, as it's better designed to handle image files. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 9):

## Using Gin to get an uploaded file

I think your question is "Using Gin, how do I get an uploaded file?". Most developers don't upload files with JSON encoding, which could be done but requires the file to be included as a base64 string (and increases the file size about 33%).

The common (and more efficient) practice is to upload the file using the "multipart/form-data" encoding. The code that others provided `file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("file")` works, but that hijacks the underlining "net/http" package that Gin extends.

My recommendation is to use [`ShouldBind`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBind), but you can also use the [`FormFile`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.FormFile) or [`MultipartForm`](http://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.MultipartForm) methods provided by the Gin package.

Examples below. Similar (but less detailed) explanations are also offered on the Gin page https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#model-binding-and-validation and https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#upload-files.

---

### Upload one file

---

#### Clients

HTML

```html
<form action="/upload" method="POST">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Curl

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/upload \
  -F "file=../path-to-file/file.zip" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```

#### Server

Go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Form struct {
    File *multipart.FileHeader `form:"file" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    // Set a lower memory limit for multipart forms (default is 32 MiB)
    // router.MaxMultipartMemory = 8 << 20  // 8 MiB

    router.POST("/upload", func(c *gin.Context) {

        // Using `ShouldBind`
        // --------------------
        var form Form
        _ := c.ShouldBind(&form)

        // Get raw file bytes - no reader method
        // openedFile, _ := form.File.Open()
        // file, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(openedFile)

        // Upload to disk
        // `form.File` has io.reader method
        // c.SaveUploadedFile(form.File, path)
        // --------------------

        // Using `FormFile`
        // --------------------
        // formFile, _ := c.FormFile("file")

        // Get raw file bytes - no reader method
        // openedFile, _ := formFile.Open()
        // file, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(openedFile)

        // Upload to disk
        // `formFile` has io.reader method
        // c.SaveUploadedFile(formFile, path)
        // --------------------
        
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Files uploaded")
    })

    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

---

### Upload multiple files

---

#### Clients

HTML

```html
<form action="/upload" method="POST" multiple="multiple">
  <input type="file" name="files">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Curl

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/upload \
  -F "files=../path-to-file/file1.zip" \
  -F "files=../path-to-file/file2.zip" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```

### Server

Go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Form struct {
    Files []*multipart.FileHeader `form:"files" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    // Set a lower memory limit for multipart forms (default is 32 MiB)
    // router.MaxMultipartMemory = 8 << 20  // 8 MiB

    router.POST("/upload", func(c *gin.Context) {

        // Using `ShouldBind`
        // --------------------
        var form Form
        _ := c.ShouldBind(&form)

        // for _, formFile := range form.Files {

          // Get raw file bytes - no reader method
          // openedFile, _ := formFile.Open()
          // file, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(openedFile)

          // Upload to disk
          // `formFile` has io.reader method
          // c.SaveUploadedFile(formFile, path)

        // }
        // --------------------

        // Using `MultipartForm`
        // --------------------
        // form, _ := c.MultipartForm()
        // formFiles, _ := form["files[]"]

        // for _, formFile := range formFiles {

          // Get raw file bytes - no reader method
          // openedFile, _ := formFile.Open()
          // file, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(openedFile)

          // Upload to disk
          // `formFile` has io.reader method
          // c.SaveUploadedFile(formFile, path)

        // }
        // --------------------
        
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Files uploaded")
    })

    // Listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you say `var json Article` where type article is defined as

```
type Article struct {
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Body string `json:"body"`
    File    []byte `json:"file"`
}
```

And File is of type `[]byte`. Type byte doesn't return anything other than what it holds

Your `Article.File` is not the same as `r.FormFile` where `FormFile` is a method that returns 3 items

So `file, header, err := json.File` isn't `file, header, err := r.FormFile("foo")`

See the implementation and method description from godocs -> [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile)

Comment: You should probably go through the gin documentation.. Here is the spot in the docs that shows you the method for gin's FormFile https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.FormFile  and this deals with uploads https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.MultipartForm.. its all there so take your time and get to know the docs.

Comment: Still could not figure out how to do that.  I need an example.

Comment: I tried `file, header, err := c.FormFile(json.File)` but I get this errro: `c.FormFile undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method FormFile)`

Comment: Read the documentation.`func (c *Context) FormFile(name string) (*multipart.FileHeader, error)` The function FormFile requires that you pass it a string. You are passing it a byte slice. `string(json.File)`  Also if *gin.Context has no field or method FormFile that's a separate question because thats included in context according to the docs.

Comment: I also tried `file, header, err := c.FormFile("file")` and get `: c.FormFile undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method FormFile)
`

Comment: It looks like this has been addressed before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970180/golang-gin-c-param-undefined-type-gin-context-has-no-field-or-method-param  chances are either your package is wrong or the version is

Comment: I guess the correct way is `file, header, err := c.Request.FormFile("file")`. This does not cause errors.

Comment: c.Request.FormFile isn't "basic" gin.. It looks like somewhere the http.Requests is being wrapped in gin.. What is the github import you are using

Comment: `"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"`

Comment: Then that's very odd.  If it works cheers.. to be sure you are using the latest version you can use `go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin`